# Laravel: Redirección según tipo usuario con Login personalizado

Tags: laravel, login, users-roles

Tegno poca experiencia con Laravel y el manejo de autenticación se me ha hecho algo complicado, más aún en este momento que tuve que crear un login personalizado por requerimientos del cliente, pero me he topado con un problema para la redirección según tipo de usuario. Que al final son dos: Merchant y Affiliate.

La tabla users contiene: id, name, email, type (Merchant o Affiliate) y password.

La autenticación es con email y password. De alli quisiera redirigir al Dashboard correspondiente a cada uno.

En web.php tengo:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

//Auth
Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Merchants App
Route::get('sign-up', 'MerchantsController@create')->name('sign-up');
Route::get('merchant-dashboard', 'MerchantsController@index')->name('merchant-dashboard');

// Affiliates App
Route::get('sign-up-affiliate', 'AffiliatesController@create')->name('sign-up-affiliate');
Route::get('affiliate-dashboard', 'AffiliatesController@index')->name('affiliate-dashboard');
```

Donde además creo estar fallando o redundando tambien en la ruta sign-up y sign-up-affiliate ya que deberia ser una sola y registrar desde el controlador UsersController.

Por otro lado en LoginController.php tengo:

```
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest', ['only' => 'showLoginForm']);
    }

    public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('auth.sign-in');
    }

    public function login(){
        $credentials = $this->validate(request(), [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            return redirect()->route('merchant-dashboard');
        }
        return back()
            ->withErrors([$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')])
            ->withInput(request([$this->username()]));
    }

    public function logout(){
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    // Método que devuelve el campo con el cual nos vamos a autenticar
    public function username(){
        return 'email';
    }
}
```

En el middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated solo modifique la función handle donde el redirect lo hago al merchant-dashboard:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/merchant-dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

En Exceptions/Handler.php solo coloque un condicional en la función render instanciando a AuthenticationException para redirigir si un usuario no esta logeado:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException){
            return redirect('/')->with('flash', 'Please log in');
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

No se si hará falta mostrar el formulario, en todo caso me comentan y actualizo esa información.

La idea es ingresar y redirigir al Dasboard correspondiente según el tipo: Merchant o Affiliate.

Espero puedan orientarme... Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Amigos, creo que ya lo logré, aunque no se si sea buena práctica y me corrigen.

En LoginController.php dentro del condicional que valida $credentials coloque otro condicional que evalua el tipo de usuario y redigire a la ruta correspondiente:

```
public function login(){
    $credentials = $this->validate(request(), [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)){
        if (Auth::user()->type == 'Merchant'){
            return redirect()->route('merchant-dashboard');
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->route('affiliate-dashboard');
        }
        return '/home_user';
    }
    return back()
        ->withErrors([$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')])
        ->withInput(request([$this->username()]));
}
```

Y en el Middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated el mismo condicional para redigirir si el usuario ya logeado intenta ir a la raíz del proyecto:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->type == 'Merchant'){
            return redirect('/merchant-dashboard');
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/affiliate-dashboard');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Hasta ahora me esta funcionando.

Pero no se si por seguridad debo hacer algo en la declaración de rutas en web.php???